# Chaplin js permanent controller that responds to routes

Tags: javascript, chaplinjs

Is it possible to have a controller that keeps its state alive and also responds to routes?
For example I would have a PlayerController that I initiate in the application's initControllers method and then I will need it also to respond to a route like /player/trackID so I can change the current playing track.

Answer (score 1):

Yes, you can create a controller which will be active for the lifetime of the application. As you mentioned instantiate PlayerController in initControllers method of the application and in routes.js define the route /player/:trackID to be bound to a specific method of the PlayerController.

e.g. route in routes.js will look like

```
match('player/:trackID', 'player#playTrack', {name:'playtrack'});
```

In the above route playTrack is the method of PlayerController.

Comment: Are you sure the router doesn't initiate a new instance of the controller? That's what I've noticed from my testing.

Comment: @NickDima, I tried and observed the same behavior as you mentioned. Whenever a route is matched a new instance is being created for the matched controller. Right now I'm also not sure how to intercept the route matching function to use already instantiated controller. If you find an answer do share it here.